# How to use ffmpeg to encode multi-channel video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, video-compression

Like nomral video have RGB/YUV, 3 channels.
Is it possible use the existing video convertor to encode more than 3 channel video? (e.g. given 5 folders of the same number and resolution pictures, generate a 5-channel video from them)
I not need to playback the 5-channel video, which is impossible for 3-channel display. I just need to encode it and then decode it back to images. Actually what I am looking for is not a playable video format, I am trying to compressing several similar video content into one file, so that hopefully they can share the motion vectors and save more space.

Dose any existing video codec support this manipulation? Or how should I rewrite some part of the exsiting video codec(some light weight implementation of H264) to support it?

Comment: Can't be done. No pixel format has more than 4 components; 4th notionally being alpha.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any 5 channel video (pixel) format ?

Comment: I dont think there is 5 channel video (pixel) format, and actually what I am looking for is not a playable video format, I am trying to compressing several similar video content into one file, so that hopefully they can share the motion vectors and save more space.